# Training 8 different classifiers with crossvalidation give same accuracy with the same file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have the script below which is supposed to use cross validation to train different models aνd then compute mean accuracy, so that I can use the best  model for a classification task. But I am getting the same results for each classifier.

Results look like this :

```
---Filename in processed................ corpusAmazon_train
etiquette  : [0 1]
Embeddings bert model used.................... :  sm
Model name: Model_LSVC_ovr
------------cross val predict used---------------- 

accuracy with cross_val_predict : 0.6582974014576258
corpusAmazon_train file terminated--- 

---------------cross val score used ----------------------- 

[0.66348722 0.66234262 0.63334605 0.66959176 0.66081648 0.6463182
 0.66730256 0.65572519 0.65648855 0.66755725]
0.66 accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.01 

Model name: Model_G_NB
------------cross val predict used---------------- 

accuracy with cross_val_predict : 0.6582974014576258
corpusAmazon_train file terminated--- 

---------------cross val score used ----------------------- 

[0.66348722 0.66234262 0.63334605 0.66959176 0.66081648 0.6463182
 0.66730256 0.65572519 0.65648855 0.66755725]
0.66 accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.01 

Model name: Model_LR
------------cross val predict used---------------- 

accuracy with cross_val_predict : 0.6582974014576258
corpusAmazon_train file terminated--- 

---------------cross val score used ----------------------- 

[0.66348722 0.66234262 0.63334605 0.66959176 0.66081648 0.6463182
 0.66730256 0.65572519 0.65648855 0.66755725]
0.66 accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.01
```

the code line for using cross_validation:

```
models_list = {'Model_LSVC_ovr': model1, 'Model_G_NB': model2, 'Model_LR': model3, 'Model_RF': model4, 'Model_KN': model5, 'Model_MLP': model6, 'Model_LDA': model7, 'Model_XGB': model8}

# cross_validation
def cross_validation(features, ylabels, models_list, n, lge_model):

    cv_splitter = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
    features, s = get_flaubert_layer(features, lge_model)
    for model_name, model in models_list.items():
        print("Model name: {}".format(model_name))
        print("------------cross val predict used----------------", "\n")
        y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, features, ylabels, cv=cv_splitter, verbose=1)
        accuracy_score_predict = accuracy_score(ylabels, y_pred)
        print("accuracy with cross_val_predict :", accuracy_score_predict)

        print("---------------cross val score used -----------------------", "\n")
        scores = cross_val_score(model, features, ylabels, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv_splitter)

        print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (accuracy_score_mean, accuracy_score_std), "\n")
```

Even when using cross_val_score, the same accuracy is give for the models. Any idea , is it perhaps I used  random_state in my cross_validation function ?

code for the definition of the models :

```
def classifiers_b():

    model1 = LinearSVC()
    model2 = GaussianNB()  # MultinomialNB() X cannot be a non-negative
    model3 = LogisticRegression()
    model4 = RandomForestClassifier()
    model5 = KNeighborsClassifier()
    model6 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50, 100, 50), max_iter=500, activation='relu', solver='adam',
                           random_state=1)
    model8 = XGBClassifier(eval_metric="logloss")
    model7 = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

    #models_list = {'Model_LSVC_ovr': model1, 'Model_G_NB': model2, 'Model_LR': model3, 'Model_RF': model4, 'Model_KN': model5, 'Model_MLP': model6, 'Model_LDA': model7, 'Model_XGB': model8}
```

Comment: Could you clean your code a little bit ? There are many things that aren't used inside your cross_validation function such as metrics or df for example.

Comment: @rolalaw is better like this, I updated it.

Comment: Thank you for the modifications ! From what I see, your code seems correct the error might come from the definition of the models or from your call of the function. Do you get the same values for the other models ? If you want a more precise answer, could you add the code used for the definition of the models and for the call of the function?

Comment: @rolalaw I added it§

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a pipeline for each model. It looks like you are performing CV on the same model on each iteration. You can check the doc [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for more information on how to use them. Then perform CV for each model pipeline.